# Add image "alt" to custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to get a page's featured image alt but my code doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
```

Here is the full Code.

```html
<div style="margin:0 auto;max-width:660px;">
    <div class="responsive-img img-networth-category">
        <picture>
            <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-width: 768px) and (min-resolution: 120dpi)" sizes="245px" data-srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=245&amp;h=245&amp;dpr=1.5 367w" srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=245&amp;h=245&amp;dpr=1.5 367w">
            <source media="(min-width: 768px)" sizes="245px" data-srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=245&amp;h=245 245w" srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=245&amp;h=245 245w">
            <source media="(min-width: 481px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-width: 481px) and (min-resolution: 120dpi)" sizes="295px" data-srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=295&amp;h=295&amp;dpr=1.5 442w" srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=295&amp;h=295&amp;dpr=1.5 442w">
            <source media="(min-width: 481px)" sizes="295px" data-srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=295&amp;h=295 295w" srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=295&amp;h=295 295w">
            <source media="(min-width: 0px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-width: 0px) and (min-resolution: 120dpi)" sizes="180px" data-srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=180&amp;h=180&amp;dpr=1.5 270w" srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=180&amp;h=180&amp;dpr=1.5 270w">
            <source media="(min-width: 0px)" sizes="180px" data-srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=180&amp;h=180 180w" srcset="<?php echo $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=180&amp;h=180 180w">
<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
            <img class=" lazyloaded">
        </picture>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, there is nothing in your question that shows what you are doing to actually obtain that information, just a standard wp function that looks like all it does is get an image url. Update your question with what you have so far tried, any code you currently have and explain what it is doing and what it should be doing.

Comment: Hi chris, have updated it. Kindly check it. i need to get image "alt" working.

Comment: Okay, all you are showing is the output code and the template that calls it, the function called is in another much deeper php file and without wanting to sound rude, I am not sure you are yet capable of making such changes. Have you looked into making wordpress templates or anything geared towards teaching you how wordpress is written?

Comment: To be honest, am not really good in this. can you help me out anyway ?